# Ruby code not executed after method call

Tags: ruby

Code is not executed (puts "hey") in the harvest method after the call to searchEmails(page).  I'm probably missing something simple with Ruby because I'm just getting back into it.

```
def searchEmails(page_to_search)
  begin
    html = @agent.get(url).search('html').to_s
    mail = html.scan(/['.'\w|-]*@+[a-z]+[.]+\w{2,}/).map.to_a
    base = page_to_search.uri.to_s.split("//", 2).last.split("/", 2).first
    mail.each{|e| @file.puts e+";"+base unless e.include? "example.com" or  e.include? "email.com" or  e.include? "domain.com" or  e.include? "company.com" or e.length < 9 or e[0] == "@"}
  end
end

def harvest(url)
  begin
    page = @agent.get(url)
    searchEmails(page)
    puts "hey"
  rescue Exception
  end
end

url="www.example.com"
harvest(url)
```

Comment: Your method is throwing exception. Remove the rescue clause from harvest.

Comment: Also, don't rescue `Exception`, rescue the exact things you want. Being to general/generic in rescues can result in very difficult to find bugs. Also, when asking about a problem in your code we need something runnable. Please read "[mcve]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@agent.get(url)` will fail with a bad url or network outage.

The problem in your code could be written as follows:

```
def do_something
  begin
    raise
    puts "I will never get here!"
  rescue
  end
end
```

Since you can't get rid of the `raise`, you need to do something inside the `rescue` (most likely log it):

```
begin
  @agent.get(url)
  # ...
rescue Timeout::Error, Errno::EINVAL, Errno::ECONNRESET, EOFError,
       Net::HTTPBadResponse, Net::HTTPHeaderSyntaxError,   
       Net::ProtocolError => e
  log(e.message, e.callback)
end
```